# Configure a pygal chart with an external conf file?

Tags: python, pygal

I'm using pygal to chart some data in a web app I'm working on and thought it would be a good idea to externalize the configuration of the chart.

So I wrote a section in my conf file that replicated my in code conf:

```
[ChartOptions]
x_label_rotation: -75
x_labels_major_every: 5
show_minor_x_labels: False
range: (30,100)
stroke_style: {'width':8}
title: Chart Title
```

and found that passing the ChartOptions section to (for instance) pygal.Config() resulted in

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygal/util.py", line 370, in mergextend
    if list1 is None or _ellipsis not in list1:
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly new at Python, so maybe this is all unnecessary, is well known or there exists a better way. I had a bunch of trouble and couldn't find anything, so here we are.

The first thing I worked out is that pygal.util.mergextend() does not like to find strings where it's expecting other datatypes. The values in the OrderedDict returned from ConfigParser.read()._sections[your_section_here] are all strings, so they need to be converted to their proper type.

Enter: ast.literal_eval().

This seemed like it would work, but kept raising a ValueError('malformed string ') on the `__name__` value, which was a str, per type(options['`__name__`']). Well, now what?

I didn't really need the `__name__` value, so I used `pop()` to remove it from the dictionary, which left dealing with the `title` value. I wanted to use `title`, knew could be a string per pygal and had control over the value of it, so what can be done?

The docs for `ast.literal_eval()` insist it allows strings, so adding quotes to the `title` value, in the conf file seemed 'reasonable', and worked.

Putting all that together, and adding flask to the mix, we get:

conf file:

```
...
[ChartOptions]
x_label_rotation: -75
x_labels_major_every: 5
show_minor_x_labels: False
range: (30,100)
stroke_style: {'width':8}
# note added quotes below
title: "Chart Title"
...
```

app.py:

```
import ConfigParser
import ast
import pygal
from pygal import Config
from flask import Flask, render_template
...
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('my.conf')
chart_options = config._sections[CHART_SECTION]
chart_options.pop('__name__')
for key in chart_options.keys():
    chart_options[key] = ast.literal_eval(chart_options[key])

@app.route('/route')
def a_route():
    global chart_options # haven't made this into a class yet...
    chart_config = Config(**chart_options)

    chart = pygal.Line(chart_config)
    ...
    # add data and finalize chart setup
    ...
    return render_template('route.html', chart=chart.render())
...
```